# How to remove <script> tags from jQuery ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to build web RSS reader. Feeds are downloaded in the background and saved to the database. I want to load news from this feeds using jQuery and ajax, to let users see all items without refreshing the website.

I'm worrying about the safety of this solution, because somebody can smuggle malicious javascript in this feeds. What can I do, to prevent malicious code?

Comment: By not allowing it in the database in the first place.

Comment: Why just script tags? What about `onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc attributes? What about `javascript:` scheme URIs?

Comment: SO questions should be thoroughly researched before posting.  Please update your question.

Comment: Returned data through AJAX should be **only** data. No HTML. One more time: **Only data**.

Comment: Why?  I return HTML through ajax all the time.

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have a variable with the responseXML. All you have to do is this:

```
$(responseXML.querySelectorAll("script")).remove();
```

Comment: this might solve is question, but it does **not** solve his problem

Answer (score 1):

You can encode HTML metacharacters:

```
responseText = responseText.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

That way if somebody says that their name is "Bob alert('haxd')

Comment: If you are going to convert **all** markup to text (not just script elements), then just insert it as a text node instead of using innerHTML.

Comment: @quentin well that's a good point, but we don't know much about what exactly is being done with the response. It may be that the stuff from the database needs to be composed into an HTML string, in which case this would make sense.